# Dojo build is removing CSS media queries

Tags: css, dojo, minify

After a recent issue, we've noticed that our Dojo build system (currently on Dojo 1.9) is skipping over media queries in CSS such as the following:

```
@media only screen
    and (orientation: landscape) {
        .imageContainer, .landscapeRightSide { display: inline-block; vertical-align: middle;}
    }
```

When I look at the output file, it never includes these rules.

There may be some complexities to our build that are causing this, but I'm not exactly sure where to start looking. Mainly, I don't even understand what internal process is used to minify the CSS. (ie, Closure Compiler or shrinksafe for JavaScript)

I'd be happy to give more information if anyone can suggest where to look.

Comment: how do you look at your output? not secretly hobbling around with portrait view? inspecting elements with chrome in the main window? .. anything special or just a plain old browser view and simply looking at the page?

Comment: Inspection of a `static/release_dev` folder in our project, in which the build places post-spritesheeted images, compressed JavaScript, etc. The way I understand it, our system copies files there, and then compresses them, or something to that effect.